# How to use my custom property as a trigger?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, triggers, styles

I have a class (Compound) binding to DataGrid. I want to change background color of a cell when a property is set to true. Here is what I tried:

```
public class Compound : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RSquaredFlagProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("RSquaredFlag", typeof(bool), 
        typeof(Compound), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    public bool RSquaredFlag
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(RSquaredFlagProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RSquaredFlagProperty, value); }
    }
    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<common:DataGridEx ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="R^2" Binding="{Binding RSquared, StringFormat=N3}">
            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                <Style>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="model:Compound.RSquaredFlag" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        </Trigger>                                                
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>                                        
            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</common:DataGridEx>
```

However, with this code, I get a compiler error "Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Background'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property".

What did I miss? How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to `Property="TextBlock.Background"` or specify a respective [`TargetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype.aspx) in your style.

I don't think the trigger will work by the way since it will look for the property on the control itself not its DataContext, use a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DataTrigger.aspx) instead.

Comment: H.B. Thank you very much for the tip. It works. 1. Change setter property to 'TextBlock.Backgroud'. 2. Use DataTrigger instead of Trigger. 3. Use regular .NET property instead of dependency property - otherwise it throws cross thread exception.